# For any affine open subset $U$ of an irreducible affine variety $X$, why $K(U)\cong K(X)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-verification, commutative-algebra

Here is a problem I met while reading *Linear Algebraic Groups* written by T. A. Springer.

The following paragraph is on Page 16 of this book.

Let $X$ be an irreducible variety. First assume that $X$ is affine. Then $K[X]$ is an integral domain. Let $K(X)$ be its quotient field. If $U=D(f)$ is a principal open subset of $X$, then $K[U]=K[X]_{f}$ from which it follows that the quotient field $K(U)$ is isomorphic to $K(X)$. And then it says that the same holds for any affine open subset $U$ by 1.3.6(ii).
(where 1.3.6(ii) is the fact that any open subset of affine variety $X$ is the union of some principal open sets.)

I'm confused with the last sentence. Here is my proof.

Proof. We write $U=\cup_{i=1}^{k}D(f_{i})$, where $f_{i}\in K[X]$ are distinct, since $U$ is an affine open subset of $X$.

Notice that $D(f_{i})$ corresponds to $\{(x,1/f_{i}(x))~|~x\in D(f_{i})\}$. 
Then $U$ corresponds to $U'=\cup_{i=1}^{k}\{(x,1/f_{i}(x))~|~x\in D(f_{i})\}$.

And $K[U]\cong K[X][T]/\cap_{i=1}^{k}(1-f_{i}T)$. For $f_i$ are different, $(1-f_{i}T, 1-f_{j}T)=1$, $\forall i\neq j$.

Therefore $(1-f_{i}T)+(1-f_{j}T)=(1)$ and $K[X][T]/\cap_{i=1}^{k}(1-f_{i}T)\cong \prod_{i=1}^{k}K[X][T]/(1-f_{i}T)$. But $\prod_{i=1}^{k}K[X][T]/(1-f_{i}T)$ is not an integral domain. Hence $K[U]$ is not integral domain. How could $K(U)$ exist?

Please tell me why, and where are my mistakes. Thanks!

Comment: It seems like you're trying to shove the $D(f_i)$ into the same ambient affine space as closed subsets. I don't think this is going to work. When $X \subseteq \mathbb A^n$ and you embed $X_f$ inside $\mathbb A^{n+1}$ that's a convenient way of saying things about $X_f$, but if you take the corresponding embedding for $X_g$ then these are not going to be compatible on the overlap. If you construction worked it would imply a lot of things about varieties that just aren't true, I think.

Comment: In general, open sets $U \subseteq X$ are not affine. So you won't be able to just write them as some closed subset in $X \times \mathbb A^k$ or something like that. Computing $K[U]$ is not so easy in general; you have to use things like the sheaf condition on $\mathcal O_X$. But actually you don't need to compute anything! You have natural restriction maps $K[X] \to K[U]$, and you only have to show that they become isomorphisms when you invert everything.

Comment: I think I know how to prove this. Define $K(X)\longrightarrow K(U)$ as $T_{i}\mapsto t_{i}$, where $t_{i}$ is the restriction of $T_{i}$ on $U$. This is surjective homomorphism. Of course, it is not a zero homomorphism. Then it must be isomorphism since $K(X)$ and $K(U)$ are both fields.    $K[U]$ is integral domain, since $X$ is irreducible and $U$ is affine open set of $X$.   I still don't understand why T.A.Springer write like that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found two mistakes in my proof. First, like Hoot said, I tried to shove the $D(f_{i})$ into the same ambient affine space as closed subsets. Second, $(1−f_{i}T,1−f_{j}T)=1$ does not imply $(1−f_{i}T)+(1−f_{j}T)=(1)$ when $f_{i}$ and $f_{j}$ is in an integral domain.