# Why is for an open subset $U\subset X$ of a variety the field of rational functions equal, i.e. $\mathbb{C}(U)=\mathbb{C}(X)$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory, affine-geometry, toric-geometry

Given any variety $X$, we can get the field of rational functions $\mathbb{C}(X)$. If we take any non-empty open subset of $U$, we get another field of rational fractions $\mathbb{C}(U)$. These fields seem to be isomorphic (see Cox Little Schenck exercise 3.0.4), which makes sense to me, but I don't know how to prove it.

I found a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1539595/for-any-affine-open-subset-u-of-an-irreducible-affine-variety-x-why-ku-c), but this solves the above question only for **affine** open subsets of $X$. Do you have any suggestions, how this can be solved for arbitrary open subsets $U\subset X$?

Comment: Glue open affines together to get $U$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field of rational functions is the stalk of the structure sheaf at the generic point. The generic point of $U$ is the same as the generic point of $X$, so the stalk at that point is the same.

Comment: Why is the generic point of $U$ the same as the generic point of $X$? It's the unique point $P$ s.t. the closure of $P$ is $X$. But how can the closure of $P$ be the open set $U$? Is there always only one generic point? For $\mathbb{A}^n$ we have the generic point $V(\{0\})$ right? What is the generic point of $\mathbb{P}^n$?

Comment: If $\eta$ is the generic point of $X$, then $\overline{\eta} = X$. Then, since $U$ is open and nonempty, $U^c$ is closed and not all of $X$. Therefore, $\eta \notin U^c$. 

Now, consider $U$ with the subspace topology. Since $\eta \in U$ and $\overline{\eta} = X$, In $U$ with the subspace topology, $\overline{\eta} = U$. 

Note that we are taking the closure of $\eta$ in two different spaces. This is why we have both $\overline{\eta} = X$ and $\overline{\eta} = U$.  

For generic points existing, see https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01IS . If $X$ is integral, the stalk is a field.

Comment: Thanks, that made it clear for me!